# Excel Formula for Timetable with Dynamic Time Increments based on Peak and Off-Peak Hours

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am quite new to excel and I currently have a list of times like this below for a bus timetable schedule. I am looking to have a formula that applies different iterations between each cell below depending on whether it is peak or off-peak hours.

Peak hours = 7:30am to 9AM and 4:30PM to 6:00PM
Off Peak hours = 9AM to 4:30PM and 6:00PM to 9:00PM

Basically, in peak hours the run time for buses should be every 15 minutes and off peak should be every 30minutes. The 15 and 30 minutes are defined in two other cells so it would be ideal if the formula would alter depending on the times in those cells, for example, if we wanted to change to every 10 and 20minutes etc.
Any help would be appreciated and hopefully my question is clear.

```
6:00
6:30
7:00
7:30
7:45
8:00
8:15
8:30
8:45
9:00
9:30
10:00
10:30
11:00
11:30
12:00
12:30
13:00
13:30
14:00
14:30
15:00
15:30
16:00
16:30
16:45
17:00
17:15
17:30
17:45
18:00
18:30
19:00
19:30
20:00
20:30
21:00
```

What I have tried / have at the moment is below. Thanks

```vb
=((IF(OR(T10>=+U$4,T10<U$3),E$7)+IF(OR(T10>=U$6,T10<U$5),E$4))/2)+T10
```

E7 cell being 30 minutes.
E4 cell being 15min.
U3 cell is 7:30am
U4 cell is 9:00am
U5 cell is 16:30pm
U6 cell is 18:00pm

Answer (score 0):

You could try this formula in cell `T2` and copy it down (assuming the timetable is to appear in column T):

```
=IF(T1="","",IF(T1+E$7>U$7,"",T1+VLOOKUP(INDEX($V$2:$V$7,MATCH(ROUND(T1,5),$U$2:$U$7)),$D$4:$E$7,2,FALSE)))
```

(the shorter the frequency of either period, the further down you should copy the formula)

[image: Screenshot illustrating effect of formula proposed]

the only 'static' part of this formula is the presumption that the period immediately prior to the last bus will be 'off peak'.

(the formula in `T1` is simply `=U2`)

Note that the labels in cells `D4`, `D7` and `V2:V7` are critical to the correct operation of the formulae.

Comment: Thank you. That is really helpful. I wondered whether you could review the formula that I ended coming up with before seeing your comment - =IF(AND($U$3<=T10, T10<$U$4), T10+$D$4, IF(AND($U$5<=T10, T10<$U$6), T10+$D$4, T10+$D$7))

Comment: @Sam ok, I see you've moved the values that were in column D to column E now - your formula _is_ more efficient, but you still need to update it so that it "stops" at the time of the last bus (in the unlikely event of your having additional "rush hours" you would have to make a lot of changes to your formula, whereas mine would just need the references updated).

Comment: Oh I think that change in column was just me playing around in excel. That is good to know, is there an easy way to apply a stop to the formula for that end of day time? I have tried your formula in my workbook and it is all functioning well so thank you for that! Maybe I will just keep yours in there and try to understand it better

Comment: @Sam Just "prefix" more `IF()` functions: `=IF(T10="","",IF(T10+D$7>U$7,"",IF(AND($U$3<=T10, T10<$U$4), T10+$D$4, IF(AND($U$5<=T10, T10<$U$6), T10+$D$4, T10+$D$7))))`